# Query nested documents in Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been struggling for a few evenings now so I hope someone can help me, it doesn't sound too complicated to me. I'm using a webhook from an external party which fires to Firebase functions everytime a change is made to an account. When this is triggered, it needs to search and update the relevant Firebase object.

My database structure is as follows:

```
- Users (collection)
   - user (document) < Includes the customerId from the webhook
    - Companies (collection)
     - company (document) < Includes the companyId from the webhook
```

To get the relevant user I've done: `const userRef = db.collection('Users').where('customerId', '==', 'webhook.customerId').get();`

This works when querying the relevant user, but the next step is to search the right company document in the collection `Companies`. This is the part where I get stuck.

To accomplish this I've tried to string it together (lol) so like: `const userRef = db.collection('Users').where('customerId', '==', 'webhook.customerId').doc().collection('Companies').where(etc... etc...` this didn't work.

I also tried `const companiesRef = db.collectionGroup('Companies').where('companyId', '==', 'webhook.companyId').get();` But that returns a 500 internal server error.

Any way I can query search nested documents in Firebase functions?

Comment: You need to get a single document to be able to retrieve its subcollection. `.where` will return a query snapshot, and I think the `.doc()` syntax is used to generating doc references when creating new documents. `If no path is specified, an automatically-generated unique ID will be used for the returned DocumentReference`

Comment: If you don't know the key of the user (which is why I'm assuming you're using a where clause), then get the first and only document from the list of results. Then access the subcollection like you are above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've found a way to include the key in the webhook request. It seems to be the only workaround for now. Do you know how you can return a child document with a path after you searched the relevant parent document?

Comment: Yes just use snapshot.forEach. Since you know there's only one match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which allows you to query across all collections with a specific name (such as all `Companies` in your case).

Firestore queries can only contain conditions on the documents that they return though, so you won't be able to check the `customerId` field in the `Users` documents. Instead, you'll need to replicate the `customerId` value in each `Companies` document, so that you can include it in the collection group query.

Once you do that, the query would become something like:

```
db.collectionGroup('Companies').where('customerId', '==', '...').where(...).get()
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer, however: `db.collectionGroup('Companies').where('companyId', '==', webhook.companyId).get();`  fires the `catch` instead of `then`. The companyId is included in the document root as a string value.

Comment: The error code I'm getting is: `failed-precondition` by the way

Comment: It works! I'm pretty new to the server side of Firebase so I didn't know you should add an index. At first I didn't get a error in the logs, so I added  `functions.logger.error(err)` to the catch. This contained the URL with the pre-filled index.

Comment: Yeah, many folks overlook the link in the error message, while it's by far the easiest way to add indexes (at least until you get a feeling for how Firestore uses indexes). Good to hear you got it working in the end 